# SQL Select data based on the group of the product

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following schema:

```
PRODUCT_MASTER_TB

PRODUCT_CODE   CATEGORY   MODEL_GROUP
     A            1            1           
     B            1            1            
     C            1            2
     D            1            2
     E            2            2

SALES_TB


SALES_DATE       PRODUCT_CODE      SOLD_QTY
20150101             A                2
20150101             A                3
20150102             A                4
20150102             B                5
20150103             B                6
20150104             C                7
...
```

What I'd like to select out of these two table is the total amount of sold qty for each product code based on the category and model group the product code is under.

For example:

```
Sales date from 20150101 - 20150104

PRODUCT_CODE   SOLD_QTY_FOR_CATEGORY_MODEL
    A                    20                   
    B                    20
    C                     7
   ...
```

A and B have the same category and model_group, so if you add their sold qty up, you get 20 each (2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6)

I thought about using fetch to solve the above problem, but is there a way of using joins to get the result I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do aggregation based on `category` and `model_group` in a sub query and join with `product_master_tb`, using `left join` to get results for all products , if there is no quantity sold for the given date range, it will return zero for such products

```
select pmt.PRODUCT_CODE , isnull(t.soldqty,0) as SOLD_QTY_FOR_CATEGORY_MODEL
from PRODUCT_MASTER_TB pmt
left JOIN (
    select pmt.CATEGORY, pmt.MODEL_GROUP, SUM(sold_qty) soldqty
    from PRODUCT_MASTER_TB PMT
    join SALES_TB ST
    on pmt.PRODUCT_CODE = st.PRODUCT_CODE
    where SALES_DATE between '20150101' and  '20150104'

    GROUP BY PMT.CATEGORY, pmt.MODEL_GROUP ) t
on pmt.MODEL_GROUP = t.MODEL_GROUP
and pmt.CATEGORY = t.CATEGORY
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a strange requirement, because you are a multiplying the total sum of `sold_qty`.  The idea, though, is to append the category and model group and then group by that information:

```
select pm.PRODUCT_CODE, SOLD_QTY_FOR_CATEGORY_MODEL
from product_master_tb pm join
     (select pm.category, pm.model_group,
             sum(sold_qty) as SOLD_QTY_FOR_CATEGORY_MODEL
      from sales_tb s join
           product_master_tb pm
           on s.product_code = pm.product_code
      group by category, model_group
     ) cm
     on pm.category = cm.category and pm.model_group = cm.model_group;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to first `sum` by `CATEGORY` and `MODEL_GROUP`, and then join that dataset back to the `PRODUCT_MASTER_TB` to get the associated `PRODUCT_CODE`:

```
with CATEGORY_MODEL as
    (
    select
        p.CATEGORY,
        p.MODEL_GROUP,
        sum(s.SOLD_QTY) as SOLD_QTY_FOR_CATEGORY_MODEL
    from PRODUCT_MASTER_TB as p
        inner join SALES_TB as s
            on s.PRODUCT_CODE = p.PRODUCT_CODE
    group by
        p.CATEGORY,
        p.MODEL_GROUP
    )
    select
        p.PRODUCT_CODE,
        cm.SOLD_QTY_FOR_CATEGORY_MODEL
    from PRODUCT_MASTER_TB as p
        inner join CATEGORY_MODEL cm
            on cm.CATEGORY = p.CATEGORY
            and cm.MODEL_GROUP = p.MODEL_GROUP
```